# Specflow: Base class for steps

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, specifications, specflow

I have a wierd instances where the order of execution is messed up

I have created a base class for all my steps definition

```
public abstract class BaseSteps
{

    static BaseSteps()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static Constructor");
    }

    protected BaseSteps()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("public Constructor");
    }


    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static void BeforeTestRun");
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void AfterTestRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static void AfterTestRun");
    }

    [Before]
    public static void Before()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Before Scenario");
    }


}



 [Binding]
    public class SpecFlowFeature1Steps: BaseSteps
    {
    public SpecFlowFeature1Steps()
    {

    }
    [BeforeScenario()]
    public void Setup()
    {

    }
```

But it's wierd that the order of execution on my debug mode looks like this

1. Base class static constructor
2. [BeforeTestRun]
3. Base class constructor
4. Child class constructor
5. Child class [BeforeScenario]
6. Base class [BeforeScenario]
   ....

I was expecting it to be like
...

3. Base class [BeforeScenario]
4. Base constructor
5. Child class constructor
6. Child class [BeforeScenario]

...

Any idea why this behave this way?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

As Sam explained, the step definitions/hooks/step argument transformations are global so you don't need base classes to share logic. I have written a post some time ago that details this a bit more: http://gasparnagy.com/2015/05/specflow-tips-problems-with-placing-step-definitions-to-base-classes/

Answer (score 0):

In specflow all steps are global, therefore there is no need to put steps in a base class and if you do this will cause issues as the steps then exist in every child class.

The solution is to make your `SpecFlowFeature1Steps` class not inherit the `BaseSteps` or to move the actual steps in `BaseSteps` into another class (if base steps contains some base functionality you want to use - but I would avoid this if possible)

you cannot rely or ordering of hooks in the way you want to. The correct approach is to use the [Order attribute](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks#hook-execution-order)